# Integer random function gave decimals

Tags: expl3

I wanted a random color stored in `mycolor`, so I wrote

```
\color_set:nnn{mycolor}{RGB}{
  \int_rand:n{256}-1,\int_rand:n{256}-1,\int_rand:n{256}-1}
```

However, it did not work correctly, so I checked it using

```
\color_show:n {mycolor}
```

Strangely, the terminal showed

```
The color mycolor has the properties:
>  model  =>  rgb
>  rgb  =>  103.99608 177.99608 239.99608.
<recently read> }
                 
l.49 \color_show:n {mycolor}
```

This clearly shows the reason--because the RGB values aren't integers!

Then I wrapped each number in the `\int_eval:n{}` command,

```
\color_set:nnn{mycolor}{RGB}{
  \int_eval:n{\int_rand:n{256}-1},
  \int_eval:n{\int_rand:n{256}-1},
  \int_eval:n{\int_rand:n{256}-1}}
```

Now it works correctly. Nevertheless, I would like to know why the integer random number function `\int_random:n{}` gave a decimal number.

Comment: I think the issue is with the `-1` being simply unsupported by `color_set`. Generally speaking you should make sure to pass exactly what each command support (e.g. by expanding the arguments) instead of hoping it works the way you show.

Comment: @user202729 Actually I was also wondering, is each part separated by the commas *integer expression*s or *integer*s? Now I suppose it is the second.

Comment: Reasonable assumption, although the documentation appears to be not quite clear on this, it says "values as **integers** from 0 to 255". "Obviously" integers should "always" work anyway, so to be on the safe side just fully expand. (with Joseph Wright's answer below it can be deduced that from the next version, integer expressions should be supported.

Comment: Please undelete the query you posted earlier today.

Comment: @Mico I may as well send a new one, if you want. The comments area is getting a bit off topic due to my problems.

Comment: Please check out the answer I just posted...

Answer (score 7):

I'd not anticipated *expressions* here as the `xcolor` 'parent' approach is quite restrictive. (Indeed, the `l3color` implementation is more laid-back as it does not *require* the values are actually integers.) The issue then arises as I've not braced the grabbed values internally, so rather than divide the whole passed value by 255, only the 1 is being divided. I will adjust the code for the next `expl3` release.

For the present, you can just use parentheses around your expressions.

Comment: You mean, you are in the among the expl3 developers? Wow.

Comment: I seem to have forgotten something. It will also work to write ```\color_set:nnn{mycolor}{RGB}{
  \int_rand:nn{0}{255},
  \int_rand:nn{0}{255},
  \int_rand:nn{0}{255}
}```